# Thoughtbots suspenders issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So i wanted to use Thoughtbots rails loader. I used RVM to update to ruby 2.1.3, and I rans some tests to make sure all of my old stuff worked. It did. 
Now when I went to run suspenders  I got some gem errors. i tried to mitigate them as best as possible.

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing capybara-webkit:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/Users/RJ/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/bin/ruby extconf.rb
Command 'qmake -spec macx-g++ ' not available

Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/Users/RJ/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/bin/ruby extconf.rb
Command 'qmake -spec macx-g++ ' not available

Makefile not found

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/RJ/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/capybara-webkit-1.3.1 for       inspection.
Results logged to /Users/RJ/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/extensions/x86_64-darwin-14/2.1.0-static/capybara-    webkit-1.3.1/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing capybara-webkit (1.3.1), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install capybara-webkit -v '1.3.1'` succeeds before bundling.
```

???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i didn't have Qt installed. This fixed everything, and all i had to do was bundle after...

*Further explanation*

So I did some googling and I found that I needed QT installed. After I install this I use RVM to change my ruby version to 2.1.3, and this proved to be somewhat difficult because I'm not used to using RVM. After I installed all this , I ran bundle installed which updated all of my gems to the latest version and then caused some other problems. But that is a different issue. Bottom line you need to make sure that you're running Ruby version 2.1.3,  and then update all gems before starting your rails project.

*On a side note, I have since going back to version 2.0 point whatever. Only because I wasn't really sure how thought box rails builder actually worked and it is going to be something I will be fixing later.*

Comment: The comment above was added, since your post was marked as *low quality* and recommended for deletion. You provided an answer to your own question, which is awesome. But maybe you can explain a little more, *what* exactly you had to do, so that others with a similar problem can profit from your solution. And btw: you can mark/check your own answer as correct if you think that there is no better answer.

Answer (score 1):

There's a requirement for capybara-webkit. I hope this helps.

https://github.com/thoughtbot/capybara-webkit/wiki/Installing-Qt-and-compiling-capybara-webkit